# riak build from source on Open SUSE 13.1 - Compile Error at eleveldb

Tags: riak, leveldb

Looking to get some assistance  around an issue while trying to build RIAK from source. Having resolved most of the issues i am now stuck with the below errors during 'make rel'

```
home/ankur/riak/deps/eleveldb/c_src/eleveldb.cc:332:58: error: invalid conversion from ‘size_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘long unsigned int*’ [-fpermissive]
if (enif_get_ulong(env, option[1], &memory_sz))
```

and

```
In file included from c_src/eleveldb.h:27:0,
from /home/ankur/riak/deps/eleveldb/c_src/eleveldb.cc:35:
/usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.2/include/erl_nif_api_funcs.h:43:27: error: initializing argument 3 of ‘int enif_get_ulong(ErlNifEnv*, ERL_NIF_TERM, long unsigned int*)’ [-fpermissive]
ERL_NIF_API_FUNC_DECL(int,enif_get_ulong,(ErlNifEnv*, ERL_NIF_TERM term, unsigned long* ip));

ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/ankur/riak/deps/eleveldb: rebar_abort
```

Can you please assist me in the right direction. I have a very limited understanding of what I am doing(just following instructions from the net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the above issue, checkout a lower tag of eleveldb. If trying on Riak2.0beta, browse to deps/eleveldb and switch working copy to tag 1.2.0
make clean and make in eleveldb then do make rel on riak. It should work !

https://github.com/basho/eleveldb/issues/106